# Bind form input field to CodeIgniter query

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to do query binding using CodeIgniter, and for the value in my array I want to reference a form input element.  What is the correct syntax to do this?

Here is the current query binding:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Municipality = ?"; 
$myQuery = $this->db->query($sql, array('Windsor'));
```

Rather than have this query filtered on the value `'Windsor'`, I want to refer to the value of `myCity` in the form called `myForm`.  Here is the form:

```
<form name="myForm">
<fieldset>
    <label>Average Sale Prices per SF 
        <input type="text" 
               id="myCity" />
    </label>    
</fieldset>
</form>
```

So, how do I substitute the array value `'Windsor'` for the form input field `'myCity'`?

Comment: on the submit of this form post it to your controller and then pass that to your query model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly take the form input field value you would write:

```
$this->input->post('field_name');
```

Comment: Do I need to use the array construct?  Or can I just use `$this->input->post('field_name');`  ?

Comment: If there are multiple ?, then you can use array construct. Otherwise you can use it as a single element.